# Paypal credit card not working in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal-sandbox

In my iPhone app i have paypal, when i test in sandbox mode with paypal email its working fine, but with credit card option transaction done successfully but money not cut from my account and also not added in merchant account.

Can anyone please help me to short it out..Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

```
[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];

PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                            configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                 delegate:self];
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try     [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];

before calling the paymentViewController.

Hope this will fix your problem